# How to module.exports another module?

Tags: javascript

I have a file we'll call `file1.ts`:

```
export { default as function1 } from 'function1.ts';
export { default as function2 } from 'function2.ts';
```

I compile this using Webpack and Babel:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  target: "web",
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib/cjs"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            "@babel/preset-typescript",
            [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                targets: ["last 2 versions"],
              },
            ],
          ],
          plugins: ["babel-plugin-styled-components"],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I publish this to npm. Now I want to import it into what we'll call `file2.ts`:

```
import { function1 } from 'package';
```

However, function1 does not exist because if I do, for example `import a from 'package';`, `a` is `undefined`.

To resolve this, I decided to create another file, we'll call `file0.js` to do the following:

`module.exports = require('./file1.js');`

if I console log the require, it will be a module object with `function1` and `function2` as i'd expect however, `module.exports = require('./file1.js');` is undefined... so I tried the following which works:

```
var test = require('./file1.js');
module.exports = { ...test };
```

1. I don't understand why that works but `module.exports = require('./file1.js');` doesn't.
2. I don't know what the correct way I should be doing this (export an es5 module / file so I can import it in es6)

Comment: Can you share a link to the npm package so I can take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem that you're seeing is because your module has no default export.

```js
export { default as function1 } from 'function1.ts';
export { default as function2 } from 'function2.ts';
```

This code exposes the default export of `function1.ts` as `function1` and the default export of `function2.ts` as `function2`, but it does not provide a default export of its own.

You could try the following instead

```js
import { default as function1 } from "function1.ts";
import { default as function2 } from "function2.ts";

export default { function1, function2 };
```

Heres a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-default-export-example-qo6y3) showing this in action. (My example mixes ts and js, but it shouldn't make a difference for what you're doing here)

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is no difference in what you mentioned. `default export` means you can import that default export by omitting the curly braces. I believe the question has a problem; I tested and it works fine.

Comment: Hi @NargesMoemenyan, I'm pretty confident in this answer, it seems like Edward found it useful as well  If you're interested, you can take a look at the sandbox I posted and try changing `my-module.js` to the first code example. You'll see an error saying `Cannot read property 'function1' of undefined`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

webpack is not designed to support emitting ES modules. Its ES module support is for apps that use ES modules internally but emit to a different format. I'd recommend using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) instead, which has full native ES module support, but can also support CJS with the same config if you still need it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to stick with Webpack for now (but I'm going to look into Rollup in the future) because I know this can work as I've seen it done before, but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.